# Cabal invalid file name "Aux" error with tcp package

Tags: windows, haskell, installation, cabal

I'm trying to install the "tcp" package but I keep getting an error like this

```
cabal.exe: Failed to unpack
tcp-0.0.2-5ea561aa2375f2b82fc69a30b0abad082069e7f8. The exception was:
Invalid file name in tar archive: "tcp-0.0.2\\Network\\TCP\\Aux\\"
```

I don't know what's happening and how to fix this, thank you.

Comment: Argh. I guess on windows you can not have a file (or directory) named `Aux` -- it's a reserved name. I have no idea about how to resolve this without having the package maintainer change the module name.

Comment: `tcp` package readme says it expects Linux. So there's probably no point in trying it on Windows anyway. What is your goal with it?